# How does AS1130 132-channel LED driver work?

Tags: led, driver, integrated-circuit

I was just checking out the [AS1130](http://www.austriamicrosystems.com/eng/content/download/185846/834724/105034) and I was wondering how you are able to drive a 12x11 array of LEDs using only 12 wires? Could anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works by what they wrongly call "Cross plexing", see Figure 24 in the datasheet.  An excerpt of this figure is shown here, which demonstrates 3 pins driving 6 LEDs.

[image]

What it should really be called is "Charlieplexing".

With Charlieplexing \$n\$ pins can drive \$n^2-n\$ LEDs.

So 12 pins can drive \$(12*12)-12 = 132\$ LEDs.

Wikipedia has a page all about it:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I kept searching for cross plexing and couldn't find anything. Thanks!